# Why does my brand new scissor jack struggle so hard to lift my car?

Tags: jack, lifting

Recently, I bought a 2 Ton Big Red scissor jack. My car weighs around 1.2 ton and each front corner of the car is no heavier than 650 - 700 kg. However, it requires so much effort to turn the jack handle and it really struggles to lift the tires off the ground so that you can change or rotate them.
I had read many positive reviews about Big Red jacks and paid almost a fortune for this product but now I'm indeed disappointed with my purchase. (Even my cheap Chinese jack was better than this).
I tried applying grease to its threads to make it perform better but that didn't make a difference either.
Why is it rated at 2 ton capacity if it can't lift as low as 650 - 700 kg?

Here are some pictures of the jack as requested:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear by what you mean by "it struggles".  Is the jack deforming or bending or do you mean it's just difficult for YOU to turn the crank.  In other words, YOU struggle to use the jack??

Comment: @jwh20 - Yes, it can be expressed in both ways. It is so hard for me to turn its handle to lift the car but it is not my fault because I could lift the same car with other jacks. That's why I say, the jack struggles not me! The jack doesn't seem to bend or deform while operating and I even checked it to raise as straight as possible.

Comment: Can you add a link to the exact jack you have purchased?

Comment: I'm not finding any "Big Red" 2 ton scissor jacks.  I only find a 1.5 ton model.  I also don't see any Big Red jacks at all that you might have "paid almost a fortune for".  The 1.5 ton model is advertised for around $27.00 at many places including Amazon.  I'd put this squarely into the category of "cheap Chinese" jacks.

Comment: @handyHowie - My jack is very much like this one but it is rated at 2 ton: https://www.amazon.com/Torin-Steel-Scissor-Jack-Capacity/dp/B004PX8BC2?th=1

Comment: @jwh20 - I can upload some pictures of my jack later. You are right about $27 not considered as a fortune to pay for anything including a jack but that's cheap for you in your country!! Here where I live, $27 means quite a fortune for middle-class people!

Comment: Can you turn the crank freely without the car resting on it?  Can you tell if there is a thrust bearing installed at the front of the threaded shaft?  Does the threaded shaft have a similar TPI to the jacks that you find easy to use?

Comment: @HandyHowie - Yes, I can turn its crank freely when it is not under load. I don't remember anything like a bearing on it but I will inspect it more closely. What does TPI stand for?

Comment: Teeth Per Inch.  Do the threads look closer together, further apart, or the same?  If the threads a further apart, then a single turn will lift the jack quicker, but it will be more difficult.  The length of each 'arm' will also make a difference.  You could turn both jacks by 10 rotations and see which has extended the most.  The quicker it extends, the more difficult it will be to turn.  A thrust bearing will also decrease friction dramatically, so lack of one will make turning the jack more difficult.

Comment: @HandyHowie - Thanks for your precious info! I think you are talking about leverage power of the jack. I will come back later with some pictures and more detailed inspection.

Comment: An photo of the spindle would be helpful

Comment: @HandyHowie - I added pictures of the jack as promised.

Comment: @Martin - Pictures are now available.

Comment: Yes, that weird economics is the difference between "GDP" and "PPP". Like for me, $27 will buy that jack, *or five loaves of bread*.  The farmer and baker are paid basically similar to me since we're competing in the same market for housing, food, and basic goods.  And probably the same for you too. But a *foreign* manufacturer wants the same hard currency (Euro/USD) from any country that buys it - that's the problem with foreign-made goods. I think of all the Ukrainian apartments with mini-split units that cost more than American A/C units... they paid a fortune for them!

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica - Agreed! Unfortunately, life is nothing but luck (at least for us!). However, depression and sadness don't do any good. If life is rubbish, death solves everything and that improves our spirits when we think about it. We should never lose our hope.

Answer (score 3):

The scissor jack needs the maximum input force at its lowest position, similar to the principle of levers. If you consider an "ideal structure" with components of zero thickness, the scissor jack at its bottom position will need an infinite force applied horizontally to make it begin to rise vertically.

An analysis of the force is shown in [Scissor Lifting Elevator Mechanism](https://erobtic.wixsite.com/erobtic/post/scissor-lifting-elevator-mechanism), which summarises:

> The maximum force needed when the angle theta [between the struts] is minimum.

This is distinct from the pitch of the screw used to raise it, the force from which is independent of the height raised.

Frankly, the scissor jack isn't a very good design. There are other designs that need a constant force regardless of the height raised. In the days when I carried a tool box in my car, it would include a simple [hydraulic jack](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/isa/160267/c1/-/en/823386_BB_02_FB/image.jpg?x=400&y=400).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The hydraulic jack you mentioned above is a bottle jack. I also thought about buying one of those but they need more maintenance than scissor jacks.

Comment: They need to be stored more carefully too (upright), and are more expensive. The car manufacturers supply a scissor jack because they are generally cheaper than a bottle jack and easier to stow. But they are not better.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian - Maintenance on a bottle jack? I have bottle jacks that are over 20 years old and have done zero maintenance (other than keeping them upright as Weather Vane suggested) on them and they still work as designed and without issue. As long as the fluid doesn't leak out, there's really very little to them.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Really? I was told that hydraulic fluid should be replaced every 2 or 3 years and that is not what an average person can do at home. If bottle jacks need zero maintenance for years, I would not hesitate to buy one. It is such a shame that I paid more for this scissor jack than a good average bottle jack! The only problem with bottle jacks is that their saddles are very small and can damage pinch welds of the car. I think a rubber pad is necessary to prevent damage. How high can bottle jacks raise the car? I need at least 15 inches of lift.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian - If the wild hair existed to change the fluid in a bottle jack, you just have to remove a small rubber plug, drain it out, then refill it. Very easy, and just the cost of the hydraulic fluid, which isn't expensive. Raise height of the jack is dependent upon the jack itself, though most have a threaded rod which can be used to take up the initial distance between jack and lifting point. I use a piece of 2x4 between jack and vehicle no matter what type of jack I'm using. It spreads the load over a large area to prevent damage.

Comment: Yeah, I've never replaced fluid in any jack, and I've had most of mine for over 30 years. They still work.  If your scissor jack isn't *being damaged* it may just be hard to turn. Make sure you lubricate the thrust bearings with something preferably non-sticky like graphite paint.

Comment: *I think a rubber pad is necessary to prevent damage.* I carried bits of wood, and I always use some protection regardless of the type of jack. Even a scissor jack with a lip that locates under the bottom seam, I will at least use a cloth to protect against scraping the paint.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica - I also have a 2.5 ton floor jack that I have been using for 8 years now. Do you mean I don't need to replace its fluid if it still works fine?

Comment: There is unlikely to be a catastrophic failure just due to old oil. In any case you should never go underneath a jacked vehicle without using rigid axle stands.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian Is it failing to lift?  Generally a jack fails when leakage causes the hydraulic fluid to leak out, so the pump element is sucking air.  It is no longer able to reach the highest positions or any position at all. Mind you I'm in a NATO nation where petroleum oils are cheaper than food oils. If someone sells jacks with food oils, all bets are off.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica - No, it is not failing. As I said earlier, my floor jack still works fine and I can raise the car easily.

Comment: A failure is more likely to be the seals than the oil. It's not exactly a high-performance situation.

Comment: @Weather Vane - I use my floor jack very rarely (once or twice every 3 months or so). Is it bad or good for it to be sitting unused most of the time?

Comment: I meant to say, "It's not exactly a high-performance situation *for the oil*." The seals, yes.